# in C# replace text with an image at the same position

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

This code is replacing the text with an image but its placing the multiple copies of an image and placing them in the beginning of the document. I want the image to be placed at the same position where text was present. My find text is available in the table cell. Is it due to that?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    //using System.Drawing;


    namespace WritingIntoDocx
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public interface IMyClass
        {

          void DocumentDigitalSign(string filep,string findt,string replacet);
        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]

       public class Program : IMyClass
        {
             public void DocumentDigitalSign(string filep, string findt, string imagepath)
            {
                string filepath = filep;
                string Findtext = findt;
                word.Application app = new word.Application();
                word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filepath);

                word.Range myStoryRange = doc.Range();

                //First search the main document using the Selection
                word.Find myFind = myStoryRange.Find;
                myFind.Text = Findtext;               myFind.Replacement.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagepath);
                myFind.Forward = true;
                myFind.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                myFind.Format = false;
                myFind.MatchCase = false;
                myFind.MatchWholeWord = false;
                myFind.MatchWildcards = false;
                myFind.MatchSoundsLike = false;
                myFind.MatchAllWordForms = false;
                myFind.Execute(Replace: word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

                //'Now search all other stories using Ranges
                foreach (word.Range otherStoryRange in doc.StoryRanges)
                {
                    if (otherStoryRange.StoryType != word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory)
                    {
                        word.Find myOtherFind = otherStoryRange.Find;
                        myOtherFind.Text = Findtext;          myOtherFind.Replacement.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagepath);
                        myOtherFind.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                        myOtherFind.Execute(Replace: word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
                    }

                    // 'Now search all next stories of other stories (doc.storyRanges dont seem to cascades in sub story)
                    word.Range nextStoryRange = otherStoryRange.NextStoryRange;
                    while (nextStoryRange != null)
                    {
                        word.Find myNextStoryFind = nextStoryRange.Find;
                        myNextStoryFind.Text = Findtext;
                        myNextStoryFind.Replacement.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagepath);
                        myNextStoryFind.Wrap = word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                        myNextStoryFind.Execute(Replace: word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

                        nextStoryRange = nextStoryRange.NextStoryRange;
                    }

                }
                app.Documents.Save();
                app.Documents.Close();
            }

        }


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Replacement.Application` is a reference to the application object. When you call `AddPicture()` on that, the picture is immediately inserted at the current position before the find operation is even executed.

I see two possibilities:

1. Load the picture, place it into the Windows clipboard and then execute the find operation specifying "^c" as replacement text. Word will replace "^c" with the current content of the clipboard. This is what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx) says:

> ReplaceWith 
>   Type: System.Object
>   Optional Object. 
>   The replacement text. To delete the text specified by the Find argument, use an empty string (""). You specify special characters and advanced search criteria just as you do for the Find argument. To specify a graphic object or other non-text item as the replacement, move the item to the Clipboard and specify "^c" for ReplaceWith.

2. Do not use wdReplaceAll, but wdReplaceNone, so that the find operation itself does not do any replacing. But you then have the chance to insert your content at the place found. Do that in a loop until no more occurrence is found.